# How to run Distributed SQL Server Query with trusted connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, trustedconnection

I want to run SQL Server query on the remote machine and this is what I am doing

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   N'remote-server',
   N'SQL Server';
//I don't want to do this step, and want to use trusted connection to remote server
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'remote-server', 'false', NULL, 'sa', 'mypassword';

select * from [remote-server].[db_test].[dbo].[test_table];

EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin 'remote-server',NULL;
EXEC sp_dropserver 'remote-server', 'droplogins';
```

I want to use the trusted connection to remote server, Is there any way so I can skip the username and password giving step and use the trusted connection as `-T` switch do in `bcp utility`?

or any other workaround? Currenty if I skip the `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` then the distributed query `select * from [remote-server].[db_test].[dbo].[test_table];` gives `authentication failed error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'remote-server' without other parameters

check the link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Tried this out but it is giving error `Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server remote-server, Line 1
Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\ummar'.`

Comment: Does the other server belong to the same domain? Then add the domain user to the other server and give him the appropriate permissions

Comment: Thanks niktrs, I have not given permission to my user on other machine.. My mistake... now its working fine.. Thanks.